# Ordenar por dia da semana, iniciando pelo dia de hoje

Tags: php, mysql, query

Quero ordenar os resultados pelos dias da semana

Tenho 7 eventos, 1 evento para cada dia, e tem que ordenar na seguinte forma:

> Domingo, segunda, terça, **quarta**, quinta, sexta, sábado

Supondo que hoje é quarta feira ele terá de mostrar todos os dados nesta ordem:

> **Quarta**, quinta, sexta, sábado, domingo, segunda, terça.

Query:

```
$sqlCmd2 = "SELECT * FROM account.events ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') ASC LIMIT 3";
```

Está funcional.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira bem simples é esta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY (
   FIELD(day, 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
   - DAYOFWEEK( CURRENT_DATE )
   + 7
) % 7
```

assim a query fica sempre relativa ao dia de hoje, e a sequência de strings não precisa ser alterada.

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3bfb/1)**.

**Pontos de interesse:**

- `FIELD` retorna a posição da string encontrada na lista, de 1 a 7;
- `DAYOFWEEK( CURRENT_DATE )` retorna o dia da semana no intervalo de 1 a 7;
- somamos 7 para que o cálculo não dê nunca número negativo; em muitos casos, nem seria necessário, mas quando se trata de usar módulo, depende da implementação específica;
- usamos o operador de resto de divisão (chamado usualmente de módulo) `%` para rotacionar o intervalo conforme o dia corrente.

**Dica:**

Se em algum momento for converter a tabela para *date* em vez de *char*, fica mais simples ainda:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY (
   DAYOFWEEK( day ) - DAYOFWEEK( CURRENT_DATE ) + 7
) % 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não seja a melhor opção, mas uma saída é criar uma coluna de `ordem` pra saber a prioridade com base no dia:

```
SELECT  events.*,
        CASE 
         WHEN dias.valor > DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
           THEN dias.valor + 1 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
         WHEN dias.valor < DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
           THEN dias.valor + 8 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
         ELSE 1 END as Ordem
FROM events
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 'Sunday' as dia, 1 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Monday' as dia, 2 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Tuesday' as dia, 3 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Wednesday' as dia, 4 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Thursday' as dia, 5 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Friday' as dia, 6 as valor
  UNION SELECT 'Saturday' as dia, 7 as valor
) dias on dias.dia = events.day
ORDER BY ORDEM
```

O `INNER JOIN` com os dia/valor é pra facilitar meu trabalho na hora do `CASE WHEN`, eu consigo saber qual é o dia da semana através do `DAYOFWEEK(NOW())` e com base nisso faço as operações, exemplo:

- Hoje é quinta-feira, o valor correspondente é número **5**.
- Então minha quinta-feira vai virar **1**, sexta-feira **2**, sábado **3**...
- Verifico no `CASE WHEN` se for dia anterior ao de hoje, então eu faço a operação `VALOR DO DIA + 8 - VALOR DE HOJE`. Então se for Domingo **1** e hoje Quinta-feira **5**, `1 + 8 - 5` = **4**.
- Verifico no `CASE WHEN` se for dia posterior ao de hoje, então eu faço a operação `VALOR DO DIA + 1 - VALOR DE HOJE`. Então se for Sábado **7** e hoje Quinta-feira **5**, `7 + 1 - 5` = **3**.
- Começando por hoje = **1**.

### [SqlFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4d7c/20/0)

Comment: o UNION é para unir uma query dentro da outra? Estou precisando de algo assim. Veja pergunta neste link:  
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94057/uma-query-para-somar-os-valores-e-selecionar-todos-os-campos-de-acordo-a-cl%c3%a1usul