# Uma query para somar os valores e selecionar todos os campos de acordo a cláusula "where" e "or" com o operador like

Tags: cakephp

No cakephp, quero fazer uma query que pegue todos os valores de acordo o parâmetro passado para o campo despesa ou para o campo data_despesa, além de somar os valores do campo valor_despesa. Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$this->Despesa->query("select sum(valor_despesa) select from despesas where despesa like '%escola%' or data_despesa like '%2015%'");
```

Só consegui resolver fazendo duas querys. Uma para encontrar e somar e a outra para encontrar todos as colunas da tabela de acordo aos parâmetros passados. Quero tudo, se possível, numa query só.

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco mais? vc quer o total igual em todas as linhas?

Comment: Esse SQL funciona? 'select sum(valor_despesa) select ...' ?

Comment: @Romario Pires  Por exemplo. Tenho 10 despesas no banco. De acordo aos parâmetros passados no where despesa like '%palavra chave%' or data_despesa like '%2015-11-15%', se eu encontrar 5 registos entre os 10 totais, quero somar o custo total das 5 despesas encontradas. Cada despesa individual tem seu custo, quero somar das 5. A query select * from despesas com as cláusulas citadas funciona. E a select sun(valor_despesa) from despesas também funciona, mas quero tudo numa query só, tipo dois select numa dml só.

Comment: @Rui Costa  tentei usar as duas instruções juntas, mas não funcionam, apenas obtenho êxito com as querys separadas. Já vium exemplo que funcionava. Só não lembro onde. Acho que foi aqui no stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndréNascimento desculpa o que vou sugerir: select sum(valor_despesa) from despesas where despesa like '%escola%' or data_despesa like '%2015%'

Não é isto que queres?

Comment: @Rui Costa  fui claro na pergunta. Quero uma query com dois comandos. Releia a pergunta.

Comment: @AndréNascimento Calma André estamos aqui para tentar te ajudar.