# Registros rotativos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-select, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como selecionar registros de forma rotativa de uma tabela. Por exemplo tenho uma tabela chamada divulgação e quero que os registros sejam selecionados de tal forma que hoje traga o elemento x,y,z. Amanha, traga y,z,x. No dia seguinte z,x,y e assim sucessivamente. Como proceder?

Comment: Quantos registros a tabela tem? O critério obviamente é o dia, mas é preciso determinar um dia inicial e um final pra rotação fazer sentido. Há ainda a possibilidade de select aleatório. Poderia definir melhor?

Comment: A tabela ainda não possui muitos registros..tem aproximadamente 20 mil e as mesmas são filtradas por categorias mas podem ser expandidas. A data inicial sempre seria o primeiro dia da semana atual e o final o ultimo dia da semana atual. Nunca fiz utilização de random select sou leigo em acesso a dados

Comment: Veja se é mais ou menos isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96472/70 - Teria que adaptar as funções, mas a lógica talvez ajude - Aqui tem um demo, pode abrir em dias diferentes que vai estar sempre começando pelo dia corrente da semana: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3bfb/1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma coluna e jogar valores aleatórios através da função RAND e ordernar por esta coluna.
Sempre que você quiser mudar a ordenação, basta setar novos valores aleatórios para esta coluna.

Comment: Solucionou o problema obrigado! tive que incorporar um job para rodar a cada dois dias e trocar os valores da coluna random e ordena-los